# can't convert List<Map> to Str[]

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a

```
List<Map> headers = (List<Map>) responseMap.get("headers");
```

with output

```
[{name=Branch}, {name=Cancel.}, {name=Trade State}, {name=Th. Sett. Dt.}, {name=Ord. Nat.}, {name=DE Code}, {name=FX}]
```

my goal is putting it into a Str[] so I tried this 
EDIT I only want the value of the list, not the {name=}

```
String array[] = new String[headers.size()];

    for (int j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++) {
        array[j] = headers.toString();
```

but I got this output

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@104eff0
```

Using Windows, JDk 1.6

Comment: Did you try `headers.get(j).toString();`. Also if you want to print the `String[]`, you should do something like `Arrays.toString(array)`

Comment: `headers.toString();` is wrong, you are getting a string representation of the `List<Map> headers`.

Comment: @Codebender I tried, doesn't work, it gives ´[Ljava.lang.String;@1826710`

Comment: Did you see my edit. While printing the String array you have to use `Arrays.toString(array)`

Comment: @mnfaria You need to override the "toString()" method of the `Map` class.

Comment: @Codebender that worked but I forgot to mention that I only want the value not the {name=}

Comment: @mnfaria Checkout my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you need to use,

```
for (int j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++) {
        array[j] = (String) headers.get(j).get("name");
```

Also, while printing arrays, you need to use,

```
Arrays.toString(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's inserting as a single string element of whole list elements.

You need iterate over the list and then put each element if list into array as a individual elements.

```
for (int j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++) {
        array[j] = headers.get(j).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `header` is a List<>, you have to use

`headers.get(j).toString()`

Because you're iterating inside the list, and you have to specify the item using `get` method.

```
String array[] = new String[headers.size()];

for (int j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++) {
    array[j] = headers.get(j).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `array[j] = headers.get(j).toString();` instead of `array[j] = headers.toString();`